# How to apply multiple nested filter in Google Analytics API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So I am trying to retrieve a report in Python using `batchGet` function with multiple filters in nested format as in `ga:Dimension1` is not null **AND** ( `ga:Dimension2` contains 'y' **OR** `ga:Dimension3`=='z'). How do  I use the `operator` keyword in a nested format under `dimensionFilterClauses`?

Edit - I have also added the code which has a single **AND** but I want to add an **OR** inside it the **AND**

```
dimensionFilterClauses= [
              {
                      
         "operator": "AND",         
              
         "filters": [
                           
         {"dimensionName": "ga:dimension1",
          "not": False,
         "operator": "REGEXP",
        "expressions": [".+"]}
         
         ,
                                                       
                           
        { "dimensionName": "ga:Dimension2",
          "not": False,
          "operator": "REGEXP",
         "expressions": [";"]}
        
          
          ]}
         ],
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` operator is defined using a semi-colon (`;`).
The `OR` operator is defined using a comma (`,`).

You can find information and example in Reporting API **filter** reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters

Comment: ya I understood this but isn't it different in v4?